# Images of Mars Phoenix Lander showing what's happened after more cycles of winter ice build-up?

Tags: mars, lander, mars-reconnaissance-orbiter, phoenix

The [Mars Phoenix Lander's End of Mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(spacecraft)#End_of_the_mission) is an interesting story. It was left in a state such that *had it survived* the Mars winter of 2008, it could potentially be contacted again in 2010.

The Phoenix landing site was above Mars' arctic circle, and it is believed that the weight of CO2 ice buildup on its solar panels was so great that they were destroyed, which is consistent with failure to respond in 2010.

The Wikipedia article links to the LATimes' 2010 article [Phoenix Mars Lander won't rise again](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2010-may-25-la-sci-mars-phoenix-20100525-story.html) as well as to an Archived copy of an Aviation Weekly article [Hello Spacecraft? Are You Listening?](https://web.archive.org/web/20110510020244/http://www.aviationweek.com/aw/blogs/space/index.jsp?plckController=Blog&plckScript=blogScript&plckElementId=blogDest&plckBlogPage=BlogViewPost&plckPostId=Blog%3A04ce340e-4b63-4d23-9695-d49ab661f385Post%3A533e9444-79a2-4787-b749-e0c33041941a) which shows the a copy of the image below.

The image itself is taken from the 2010 BBC News article [Nasa's Phoenix Mars lander 'broken by ice'](https://www.bbc.com/news/10151001).

**Question:** Are there any more recent images of the Mars Phoenix Lander showing what happened to its structure after even more cycles of winter ice build-up?

---

[image: Nasa's Phoenix lander broke apart during Mars' winter: Before] [image: Nasa's Phoenix lander broke apart during Mars' winter: After]

[image: Nasa's Phoenix lander broke apart during Mars' winter]

> A much diminished outline is apparent in the latest images. Credit NASA
>
> New images appear to confirm that Nasa's Phoenix lander broke apart during Mars' winter.

Answer (score 1):

[image: enlarged part]

The image above is an enlarged part of a [HiRiSE image](https://uahirise.org/ESP_025786_2485) captured in Januari 2012, and the only other one that I could find.

Comment: Yep, there it is. Excellent space detective work, thank you!

Comment: @uhoh  Thank you too, i didn't realize before that already at 68$⁰$ latitude such a thick layer of dry ice is deposited.